# Enter a value in a non-standard HTML textbox

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm attempting to edit this textbox using VBA:

```
<td id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ProfileEditorValueAboutMe" class="ms-authoringcontrols" valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;"><span class="ms-profilevalue"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ProfileEditorEditAboutMe"><DIV id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ProfileEditorEditAboutMe_editableRegion" class="ms-rtestate-write ms-inputuserfield ms-long" contentEditable="true" InputFieldId="ProfileEditorEditAboutMe_hiddenRTEField" style="height:125px;overflow:scroll;background-color:white;"><p>text box content here</p></DIV></span>
                        <div class="ms-profiledescription" style="width: 386px; white-space:normal;">Please enter some details in the textbox</div>
                        </span>
                        <table border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
```

Here is the VBA, which performs as expected, other than that the textbox doesn't change (either on screen or when the form is saved by the click event):

```
    Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium 
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "URL"

While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend


Debug.Print ie.Document.getelementbyid("ProfileEditorEditAboutMe_hiddenRTEField").Value
ie.Document.getelementbyid("ProfileEditorEditAboutMe_hiddenRTEField").Value = "<p>123</p>"
Debug.Print ie.Document.getelementbyid("ProfileEditorEditAboutMe_hiddenRTEField").Value

ie.Document.all("Button1").Click
```

The `.value` property does change, but the textbox does not.

I would be grateful for any ideas.  As you can probably tell, I'm fairly new to VBA webscraping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're manipulating the value of the textbox yourself, you'll need to fire the `onchange` event in order for the textbox to repaint itself with your new value. This is done by creating an event object and then calling it via the `dispatchEvent()` function.

```
Dim e
Set e = ie.Document.getelementbyid("ProfileEditorEditAboutMe_hiddenRTEField")

' Set the value...
e.Value = "123"

' Fire the "onchange" event...
Dim objEvent
Set objEvent = ie.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
objEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
e.dispatchEvent objEvent
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get an object not found, which I think is because there's a new way of specifying events: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn905219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.  Just trying to work out how to translate this into the new syntax.

Comment: It should work fine. As noted in the article, _"the createEvent()/initEvent() syntax remains functional at this time to support backward compatibility"_. What line causes the error?

Comment: Sorry, to be more precise, it's a "Object doesn't support this property or method" error on this line: Set objEvent = ie.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents").  Could it be because I'm using the InternetExplorerMedium object (which I have to for security reasons)

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. `InternetExplorerMedium` is supposed to support the same events. Can you try switching it to the full-featured IE just to test?

Comment: Explicitly defining objEvent as an IDOMEvent and document as an HTMLDocument fixes that problem.  Now the e.dispatchEvent line fails with the same error.  If I define e as an Element, dispatchEvent fails.  If I define e as an IEventTarget, the "Set e=" line fails with a type mismatch.